# How to confirm before deleting in Laravel Route:resource

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade, boot

In Laravel using Route::resource, the method should be "DELETE" instead of "GET" to  delete a row/record so I have to use `Form` like this.

```
<form action="{{ route('category.destroy', $category->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Delete</button>
</form>
```

it is working fine but I want to confirm before deleting.
I can show bootstrap model for confirmation but am unable to pass and use the $category->id in the model.

is there any better way.

Comment: Please try searching before posting a new question.  For eg a quick search for your question keywords "*laravel confirm delete bootstrap modal*" turns up many questions here on SO with answers and code you can copy paste, or at least ideas to get you further along the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel bootstrap delete confirmation using modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880366/laravel-bootstrap-delete-confirmation-using-modal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've done it like this. I used `<a>` tag to show delete confirmation model and passed `route` and `category->id` to `href`.

```
<a href="{{ route('category.destroy', $category->id) }}" 
class="text-danger w-4 h-4 mr-1 btnDelete"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#deleteCategoryModel">
<i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color: #d11010;"></i>
</a>
```

included the `from` in the bootstrap model with `action = ""`

then in jQuery I get the value of `href` of clicked `<a>` tage and passed it to `action` attribute of the `form` in the bootstrap model.

```
$('#deleteCategoryModel').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var route = $(button).attr('href');
            $('#delete-category-form').attr('action', route);
        })
```

and this is the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can user bootstrap modal but i suggest you sweet alert its easy and perfect . You will see a confirmation message before you delete the record and if you want delete record using bootstrap modal use this above form inside modal like image i have sent.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INvG4.png)

Good Luck!